# colon(:) and dot(.) as millisecond separator in datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have migrated a Sybase database to **SQL server 2008**.
The main application that using the database trying to set some of dateTime2 column with data like `1986-12-24 16:56:57:81000` which is giving this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Running the same query using dot(.) instead of colon(:) as millisecond separator like `1986-12-24 16:56:57.81000` or limiting the milliseconds to 3 digits like `1986-12-24 16:56:57:810` will solve the problem.

**NOTE:**
1- I don't have access to the source of application to fix this issue and there are lots of table with the same problem.
2. Application connect to database using ODBC connection.

Is there any fast forwarding solution or should i write lots of triggers on all tables to fix it using the above solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can't fix the application and the column is again used in the same application (or others that you have no control over), I'm afraid `INSTEAD OF` triggers might be your only solution...

Comment: @MK_ not working As Gordon Linoff said: A trigger on the current table is not going to help because the type conversion happens before the trigger is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS Gordon Linoff said

> A trigger on the current table is not going to help because the type
>   conversion happens before the trigger is called. Think of how the
>   trigger works: the data is available in a "protorow".

But There is a simple answer!
Using **`SQL Server Native Client Connection`** instead of basic `SQL Server ODBC connection` handle everything.

Note:
1. As i used SQL Server 2008 version 10 of SQL server native client works fine but not the version 11 (it's for SQL Server 2012).
2. `Use Regional Settings` make some other conversion problem so **don't** use it if you don't need it.

Comment: Very appropriate solution for your problem.  Don't read the data from Sybase in the wrong format!

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes of course. everything migrated and sybase not used anymore if all tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need triggers?  You can use `update` to change the last `':'` to `'.'`:

```
update t
    set col = stuff(col, 20, 1, '.');
```

You also mistakenly describe the column as `datetime2`.  That uses an internal date/time format.  Your column is clearly a string.

EDIT:

I think I misinterpreted the question (assuming the data is already in a table).  Bring the data into staging tables and do the conversion in another step.

A trigger on the current table is not going to help because the type conversion happens before the trigger is called.  Think of how the trigger works:  the data is available in a "protorow".

You *could* get a trigger to work by creating views and building a trigger on a view, but that is even worse.  Perhaps the simplest solution would be:

- Change the name and data type of the column so it contains a string.
- Add a computed column that converts the value to `datetime2`.

Comment: "Your column is clearly a string." -- The data coming from the application is clearly a string, but I'm not seeing anything in the question that makes me doubt that the column is of type `datetime2` as the OP says it is. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hvd . . . `datetime2` doesn't use a colon to separate fractional seconds.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why the OP is getting the error. If the column had a string type, the data would be silently inserted without any issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff here a sample query that i get the error:  `UPDATE dbo.Works SET completed = '1986-12-24 16:56:57:81000' where ...`. The previous (Sybase) database accept this but sql server accept just 3 digits after colon. And as you said ` the data is available in a "protorow".` so no way to solve this?

Comment: @osyan . . . Change the name and data type of the destination column to a string and add a computed column with the name `completed` that does the transformation (that way, you only change the DML queries not any others).

Comment: @GordonLinoff surprise :) found a simple way. going to post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Select REPLACE(getdate(), ':', '.')

But it will Give String Formate to datetime Which is not covert into DateTime formate